# Wilcoxon V Statistic or W Statistic - interchangeable?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have seen reference to the W, V and T statistics all within the Wilcoxon Signed rank Test, and this has me confused.
First question: Are these used interchangeably?

My test is the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test because I'm comparing non-parametric matched scores for a before / after ordinal measurement scenario.

(If it's of interest, the pre / post scenario is basically whether respondents give different answers to the same question when extra information is added)

I gather from this very useful post here [Output of one-tailed Wilcoxon sign rank test in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41620/output-of-one-tailed-wilcoxon-sign-rank-test-in-r)   by @Glen_b that the V Statistic is simply the Signed Rank Statistics.

I presume this means I cannot extrapolate too much from the size of it?
I.e I could have a P score of less than 0.05 with a large V statistic, or a P value of less than 0.05 with a low V statistic.

Second question: What can the V statistic tell me?

I am trying to work within the CrossValidated guidelines so please bear with me if I have made a mistake with this post.

Henry